# Change style of TabItem component of svelte flowbite

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, svelte, flowbite

Actually, I am trying to change the style of a TabItem of svelte flowbite. The problem is that I want to change some things like the background-color or the color of the text and it doesn't work properly.

As written in the [documentation](https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/components/tab#TabItem), I can put the class prop to overwrite the li tag class. I tried changing styles with it but there are two things that I saw :

1. Background color only changes when I put the style "underline" of the Tabs component, and it's ugly.
2. Changing text colors doesn't work at all.

I'm using tailwind for the style.

Code :

```
<TabItem open title="My tab item" class="bg-red-500 text-yellow-200">
```

[Actual result (colors are for demo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfTHF.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQlcE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the defaultClass prop in the Tab component.

```
<Tab defaultClass="bg-red-500 text-yellow-200">
```